# How to cite a drug name in AMA Style journal article?

Tags: publications, citations, journals, citation-style, bibliometrics

In my paper, I have used a drug name called `Metformin`. But I received a comment from Editor to cite the drug name.

May I know how can I cite the drug name in AMA style?

There could be multiple suppliers/companies that produce/manufactures this drug from a different location

Can help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you cite drug package inserts.

See Chapter 3.13.6 of the [AMA Manual of Style](https://www.amamanualofstyle.com/view/10.1093/jama/9780190246556.001.0001/med-9780190246556) (11th ed.):

> Package inserts, patient information, and prescribing information (the material about the use and effects of the product) may be cited as follows:
>
> 1. Zithromax. Prescribing information. Pfizer; 2017. Accessed June 23, 2019. https://www.pfizermedicalinformation.com/en-us/zithromax
> 2. Azilect. Package insert. Teva Pharmaceuticals Inc; 2014.

The general pattern, as I see it, would be: `Drug. Type-of-document. Manufacturer. Date. Optional-internet-access-date. Optional-internet-source.`.

If there are multiple manufacturers for one drug, you could cite all of them (as long as that seems appropriate for the specific context within your publication).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Upvoted...My question is there could be multiple suppliers of a drug. Am I right? Should we use manufacturer name? In your example above, Teva Pharmaceuticals in Manufacturer name?

Comment: For ex: Metformin may have multiple manufacturers. Should we just pick some random one?

Comment: I edited the post to add more information on multiple manufacturers. I would cite each manufacturer (as long as it seems relevant to your paper).

Comment: Sorry, am new to this. Your answer is for Bibliography citation? May I know how can we do it for in-text citation?

Comment: Or there is nothing like bibliography reference text for  drugs?

Comment: If you use the AMA Style, I suppose you use superscripts, as in `The drug Metformin² is used for the present experiment` - right? And then the superscript `²` leads to the bibliographic references regarding the drugs (in the form outlined in my answer).

Comment: @The Great Did you capitalize metformin in the middle of a sentence?  In the middle of a sentence, the term will seem to be a brand name. Uncapitalized, metformin is the generic term for the chemical moiety--N,N-dimethylbiguanide. As noted, there are many manufacturers of metformin and many brand names for this chemical entity.  Unless your paper is about a specific brand of metformin, you should write--metformin (uncapitalized except as first word in a sentence) and give the chemical formula in parentheses.  "This study involved the drug metformin (generic term for N,N-dimethylbiguanide)"

Comment: @DianaPetitti - Thanks for your response. Upvoted